# Android - How to convert Scanned barcode to a string?

Tags: java, android

I have created an app which makes use of the zxing barcode scanner to scan a barcode as part of an input form with the following code in mainActivity.java:

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

          public void onClick(View v){
            if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
          }

        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
          IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
          if (scanningResult != null) {
          String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
          String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
          formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
          contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            }
        }
```

Then I have assigned my text input values here:

```
String postCode = etPostCode.getText().toString();
String address1 = etAddress1.getText().toString();
```

and used the following code to try and do the same with the scanned content value:

```
    String scanVal = ((s)findViewById(R.id.scan_content)).toString();
```

and then added it to the last part of my code

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Record...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new SignupActivity(this).execute(postCode, address1, scanVal);
```

}

I then send the values to my webserver to be saved to a database when the submit button is clicked and Alas, it does not work.

I get the text values of 'postcode' and 'address1' but there is no scan field, its just an empty field in my database.

Can anybody see where I have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it by doing:

```
String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                 String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
```

Comment: hello. Are you saying tha I may use the 'contentTxt' to pass with the other values? such as: new SignupActivity(this).execute(postCode, address1, contentTxt);